# Mirth connect Message Prune setting

Tags: mirth

Currently I am using **mirth connect 3.0** in 3.0. It is not possible to prune the error messages.

I have a plan for upgrading to 3.5.

My question is, in **mirth connect 3.5** is it possible to prune error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errored messages are still not included in pruning, but that's something we're planning on adding in the near future.